# can i use <defs> to create multiple polylines?

Tags: javascript, svg

Using the svg components `<defs>` and `<use>` works for circles and ellipses, but I'm having trouble using them to create multiple `<polyline>`s.

Here is my code:

```
svg width="900" height="900"
            defs
                g id="POL"
                    <!--circle style="fill: inherit;" r="10"/-->
                    <polyline style="fill:black;stroke:red;stroke-width:1">
                    <line style="stroke:black;stroke-width:1.5"/>
                g
            defs
            <use points="0,10 25,10 35,20 5 25" xlink:href="#POL" />
            <use points="12,10 20,30 15,35 5 25" href="#bateau"/>
            <use points="12,4 10,28 10,30" href="#POL" style="fill:red;">
svg
```

Comment: I've edited you question to give it basic formatting, but what you posted is not valid code. I'll let it for you to review again and edit your post.

Comment: Please edit this a little more. You should not use multiple exclamation marks, or combinations of exclamation marks with question marks, because it looks as if you're shouting. Use capital letters at the starts of sentences. These things may seem trivial but they create a better feeling of confidence in the reader, and give more of an impression that you're being polite.

Comment: If you want to display different polylines, simply create different polylines in markup. There's no reuse here and your use of a <use> tag is not appropriate. <use> tags are really for displaying exactly the same thing multiple times.

Comment: I edited the question's prompt to make it easier to comprehend. Please edit it to give it a better description of the problem than "doesn't work" or "having trouble".

Answer (score 0):

[`points` is not a valid attribute for a `use` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#UseElement), but `width`, `height` `x` and `y` are. That's why some `rect` and `circle` attributes can be altered by adding them to a `use` element, but not `polyline` attributes (note, if you try to change the `r` of a circle, that doesn't work either.)

(It seems like you are trying to repurpose defs/use as a style abstraction. This is what CSS is for.)